# указать путь прямой путь src audio

Tags: html, аудио

Подскажите есть ли какие то ресурсы откуда можно подключить прямую ссылку на песню, чтоб уменьшит размер своего проекта. Иначе получается, что помимо основных файлов index.html, style.css и  script.js, в папке хранятся куча песен, а они только увеличивают размер проекта. на гитхаб его не загрузить ибо максимальный размер там 25 мб, очень нуждаюсь в такой информации, или возможно есть другое решение данной проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, с ВКонтакте:

```html
<audio src="https://psv4.vkuseraudio.net/c611928/u371745435/audios/7158c2c68adf.mp3" controls>
```

Comment: По ссылке ошибка 404

Comment: @andreymal странно... у меня по ссылке Луи Армстронг ))

Comment: А вы с другого компьютера/телефона её откройте (через другой интернет)